# How to do a "NOT IN" expression using the Criteria API in NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate

I am able to use the NHibernate Criteria API for an IN statement using

```
new NHibernate.InExpression()
```

Is there a way using the Criteria API to get a "NOT IN" statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a NotExpression around it.